# My dashcam microSD card flew out; how can I look for it in hard to reach spots?

Tags: dashcam

I have a dashcam in my vehicle which has a micro-SD card slot.  This morning when I was trying to eject the card so I could transfer footage off, and swap it out with a different one, my hands failed me and instead of catching the card it slipped/flew out and landed in regions unknown.  From the sound it made I couldn't tell where it landed.  After spending about an hour with a flashlight searching all the nooks and crannies of the vehicle without finding it, I realized that there are a lot of hard to reach places where it could have gone.  In particular, there are some places under the seat where there are gaps in the floor fabric that appear to lead to voids of sorts between the fabric and the metal frame.  While I was near one of these I actually found a different micro-SD card slot that had been lost for several months.

I tried using a vacuum cleaner, but it's not clear to me whether I should have expected any success here, as I can barely get the end of the hose/attachment to touch the gap in the fabric under the seat, much less try to work it into the gap and try to reach beyond that point.  In addition, I feel like pushing the vacuum clean around (or for that matter, just trying to reach my hands in places I have trouble seeing) may risk push anything tiny like a micro-SD card deeper and further out of reach.

For that matter, there are a lot of unlikely but possible places it could go that I'm at a loss how to reach or even look.  For instance, it seems very bounced off my hand and flew at just the right angle to go through the gap in the ceiling molding.  For that case I can shine my flashlight through the windshield and just barely see into the gap but not enough, and I can pull the molding down slightly but not enough to reach in far enough to feel around for the card.

Are there any tricks or tip I could use to access these difficult to reach places?  This is a 512GB card and it has footage I would like to get off the card, but I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are relatively inexpensive inspection cameras on the market. A search on Amazon for "endoscope camera" provides phone based devices from US$20 - US$30 and up. Once you locate it with the camera, a similar grappling device can be used to collect it.

Comment: Oh now that's a clever idea!

Comment: It took about half an hour trying to wiggle my new endoscope around and get it to focus on the various nooks and crannies under the driver's seat, but I found it!  Thanks for the excellent suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

While you may not think it is, in most vehicles it is VERY EASY to remove the seat. It usually only involves four fasteners and a plug for power and/or airbag. You wouldn't need to pull it all the way out, just enough to move it around so you can find your SD Card.

If that doesn't lend well to finding it, it's a crap shoot. More than likely it is in and around the seat somewhere. If after pulling the seats you still don't find it, then your guess is as good as anyone's. You'll have to start pulling other "likely" places it could have gone. And there are thousands of them, really. If the SD Card is that important to you, you may end up having to pull the entire interior to find it. Start with the easier stuff (ie: facia, center console) and leave the harder stuff to last (ie: dash).

Comment: Thanks!  Is there some easy way to pull the ceiling molding (for lack of a better term)?  It's not clear to me that there is any way to release it - maybe it snaps out if i apply pressure in the right spot (or breaks/deforms if I do it wrong!).  The dash cam wiring is already hidden by running it through part of this area.

Comment: @Michael - I wouldn't know, because I don't know what the year/make/model of your car is. Even then, I'm doubtful I'd have any more information for you. I'll tell you this, most interior parts are pretty easy to remove and replace. Most just pop out with the right amount of pressure.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - well, the right amount of pressure in the right place with perhaps the right shaped tool. But likely there is a YouTube video out there of somebody taking various bits out of the same model, showing where and how to do it.

Comment: @JonCuster - Oh, I'd just about guarantee you there is ... but I can't relate any of that without the vehicle information.